# [Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/ubuntu/.hfc-key-store/

Tags: amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04, hyperledger-composer

I am getting following error while running composer rest server. I am using aws ubuntu 16.04 server.

Hyperledger Composer

? Enter your Fabric Connection Profile Name: hlfv1

? Enter your Business Network Identifier : digitalproperty-network

? Enter your Fabric username : admin

? Enter your secret: Xurw3yU9zI0l

? Specify if you want namespaces in the generated REST API: never use namespaces

? Specify if you want the generated REST API to be secured: No

To restart the REST server using the same options, issue the following command:
   composer-rest-server -p hlfv1 -n digitalproperty-network -i admin -s Xurw3yU9zI0l -N never

Discovering types from business network definition ...

> Connection fails: Error: error trying login and get user Context.
>   Error: error trying to enroll user. Error: Failed to generate key for
>   enrollment due to error [Error: EACCES: permission denied, open
>   '/home/ubuntu/.hfc-key-store/be8405cef82cc00455de296664ccdcb35e4c707bb0e63a00d0bef76546528e13-priv']
>   It will be retried for the next request. Error: error trying login and
>   get user Context. Error: error trying to enroll user. Error: Failed to
>   generate key for enrollment due to error [Error: EACCES: permission
>   denied, open
>   '/home/ubuntu/.hfc-key-store/be8405cef82cc00455de296664ccdcb35e4c707bb0e63a00d0bef76546528e13-priv']
>       at client.getUserContext.then.then.catch (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.0/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-connector-hlfv1/lib/hlfconnection.js:293:34)
>   ubuntu@ip-172-31-19-220:~/composer-sample-networks/packages/digitalproperty-network$

Answer (score 0):

when connecting to the running v1.0 Fabric dev environment using hlfv1 or running the REST server (as shown above) - you need to provide the default admin password of 'adminpw' - please try running composer-rest-server again and use the correct password. cheers Paul

Comment: Thanks Paul. I tried with using adminpw password. But it gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

On the similar set up, I could able to work with following command, basically use PeerAdmin user instead of admin. For example:

```
composer-rest-server -p hlfv1 -n my-network -i PeerAdmin -s PeerAdmin -N never
```

If you still face same issue, try with sudo

Comment: Thanks Nishikant. I am getting below error while running above command using sudo.                                                                        
                                                                                                            
 Error: Failed to load connector module "composer-connector-hlfv1" for connection profile "hlfv1" at connectionProfileStore.load.then.e (/usr/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-common/lib/connectionprofilemanager.js:151:27)